# Mobject position not updating in "MANIM" after the animation is done

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, manim, algorithm-animation

When I'm animating   using
self.play(mobject.animate.move_to())
the object in the screen is moving but what I've observed is that the values are not updating to the new position How can I do that